# DateTime.TryParseExact's result has DateTimeKind.Unspecified despite the input date time string contains timezone information

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

```cs
string dateTimeStr = "2020-01-02T04:00:00Z";
string[] formats = { "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fff'Z'" };

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateTimeStr, formats,
                        null,
                        DateTimeStyles.None,
                        out DateTime dateValue))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dateValue.Kind); // why set to DateTimeKind.Unspecified here?
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine(dateValue);
}
```

By this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netframework-4.6.2#System_DateTime_TryParseExact_System_String_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_System_Globalization_DateTimeStyles_System_DateTime__):

> If `s` contains time zone information, the time is converted to local time, if necessary, and the `Kind` property of the returned `DateTime` object is set to `DateTimeKind.Local`.

However, in the commented line, the `dateValue`'s `Kind` field is set to `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`, despite the tailing 'Z' in the `dateTimeStr` to specify its timezone as Utc.

I don't know how it happens and my goad is to have the output `DateTime` has its `Kind` set to `DateTimeKind.Utc`. How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

`'Z'` is just an escaped literal letter Z that does not mean anything (same for the `'T'`). The time zone specifier in the format string [is `K`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6629774/11683).

```cs
string[] formats = { "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssK", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffK" };
```

This will give you `DateTimeKind.Local` like documented, and then you call [`.ToUniversalTime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.touniversaltime?view=netcore-3.1) on the result to get to the UTC.

Comment: Verified answer from GSerg in unit test, only first format works with test date though